# Writing a bookmarklet that counts word frequency

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, word-frequency

I want to create a bookmarklet that counts up all the text on a webpage and then displays the results from most to least it in a absolutely positioned div.

Every google search i've done talks about counting the total number of words in a form or text area or known div id.  That's not what i want.  I want the number of times each /w appears on the entire webpage.

I know enough javascript to know that i don't know how to do this.

Comment: You might also want to look at https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/seo.html -- there's an word frequency bookmarklet there that works quite well.

Comment: Your google-fu is failing you. Search for `bookmarklet word frequency` and possibly `seo bookmarklet word frequency`. I see plenty of good hits.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
function countWordFrequency() {
  var freq={};
  // Traverse the DOM looking for text nodes.
  recurseTextNodes(function(textNode) {
    // Split the text into words, removing punctuation.
    var words = textNode.data.replace(/[^\w\s]/g, '').split(/\s+/)
      , len = words.length;
    // Count the word frequency.
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
      // if (freq[words[i]]) { bug if one of the words is "constructor"!
      if (typeof freq[words[i]] === 'number') {
        freq[words[i]] += 1;
      } else  {
        freq[words[i]] = 1;
      }
    }
  });
  return freq;
}
```

This solution might be overly simple in the way that it removes punctuation and parses words but should demonstrate the idea.  Also the `recurseTextNodes` function is left as an exercise to the reader =).  There are also implications of how to store this routine as a bookmarklet (esp. how to display the results to the end-user) but again, I'll assume you've got some idea of how to do that.

Comment: hi, your code is almost perfect, but there is a bug if the text contains, for example, the word "constructor". See Douglass Crockford's explanation here:
http://oreilly.com/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/awful-parts.html#object